# How to make rectangular image appear circular with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I've used `border-radius: 50%` or `border-radius: 999em`, but the problem is the same: with squared images there's no problem, but with rectangular images I obtain an oval circle. I'm also disposed to crop a part of the image (obviously). Is there's a way to do that with pure CSS (or at least JavaScript / jQuery), without using a `<div>` with a `background-image`, but only using the `<img>` tag?

Comment: you can only make circle from square using border-radius. border-radius doesn't increase or reduce heights nor widths

Comment: You should provide an example as a jsfiddle of what you are looking for. Why cannot you use a DIV instead? Why cannot you set background image of IMG tag? Etc..

Answer (score 57):

I presume that your problem with `background-image` is that it would be *inefficient* with a source for each image inside a stylesheet. My suggestion is to set the source inline:

```
<div style = 'background-image: url(image.gif)'></div>

div {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNh8t/2/)</kbd>

Comment: You could even use it with an IMG tag too

Comment: Since their issue is with rectangle's and not squares, this won't work. Have the div set with a fixed width and height with overflow: hidden. Have the child div set to fill the div and the overflowed areas are gone, so it will be a circle. Also the img should be a display of block to remove possible whitespace...

Comment: GCyrillus, its because the width and height are not a square. It has to be a square.

Comment: OP question is too ambiguous, she needs to provide current code she's using to let us see what she's talking about. Is IMG got size fixed or not, cannot she used a conatiner, etc... As i read it @David's comment seems fair

Comment: @fzzle , nop a rectangle cannot be turn in a circle with border-radius, it was the question :)if that is an image or not

Comment: @GCyrillus Ya but then why OP is not setting IMG as square? Why she couldn't? It could have a reason, but which one?! Looks like OP is on vacation currently, she doesn't answer any question...

Comment: @A.Wolff we all know that the way is to crop it within a wrapper :), she wishes not and thinks still it is possible., it is a misunderstanding of border-radius, she has to keep going on and use one cropping method.

Comment: @fzzle i do not like much this way . in order to work , you need a transparent image to see background, and reset background for any image. then , if image has a meaning in the content, it totally disseapear from document(and search engines ) , fine if it is only for decoration . OP doesn't say, i agree, but you should give some warnings about the practice you propose.

Comment: @fzzle Stop bombing your answer by continuous editing. Also you should use a transparent image as value of `src` attribute of the `<img>` element in order to fix the visual issue in web browsers such as IE.

Comment: @HashemQolami What visual issue?

Comment: @fzzle The default icon which appears when the `src` is missed or the URL is broken.

Comment: @HashemQolami .. I can't see it, but in case you don't want this to happen you can just use a div instead.

Comment: this answer almost worked for me.  I just needed to add "background-size:cover" to shrink a larger image down.

Comment: Also, add `background-size : cover`

Answer (score 38):

My 2cents because the comments for the only answer are getting kinda crazy. This is what I normally do. For a circle, you need to start with a square. This code forces a square and will stretch the image. If you know that the image is going to be at least the width and height of the round div you can remove the `img` style rules for it to not be stretch but only cut off.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .round {
                border-radius: 50%;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
            }
            .round img {
                display: block;
            /* Stretch 
                  height: 100%;
                  width: 100%; */
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="round">
            <img src="image.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MrX Stupid?! Could you elaborate?

Comment: at least you should set min-width:100% and min-height:100% to image to make sure it fills container , width and height might change ratio of image and make it look weird :)

Comment: @GCyrillus, wouldn't setting the width and height do the same thing?

Comment: @David , not not really, it will shrink or xpand your image to a square

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks. Going to change this on a few of my sites now.

Comment: Can you put this in a JSFiddle or some other site? It won't work for me.

Comment: @bafromca are you growing or shrinking your images? I uncommented his code because I was shrinking mine, and it worked.

Comment: Problem with min-width and min-height is that if you have an image that is (much) larger than 150px, only part of the image is shown.

Comment: This has been a nice solution, provided that the image is rightly centered and all details are in the correct place.
However, when setting the position absolute on the image, the border radius on the parent div stops taking effect.
Any ideas how to position image so border radius is around desired area of image?

Answer (score 12):

For those who use Bootstrap 3, it has a great CSS class to do the job:

```
<img src="..." class="img-circle">
```

Comment: turns rectangular images into ovals, not circles!

Answer (score 4):

you can only make circle from square using border-radius.

border-radius doesn't increase or reduce heights nor widths.

**Your request is to use only image tag , it is basicly not possible if tag is not a square.**

If you want to use a blank image and set another in bg, it is going to be painfull , one background for each image to set.

Cropping can only be done if a wrapper is there to do so. inthat case , you have many ways to do it

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer from @fzzle - to achieve a circle from a rectangle **without defining a fixed height or width**, the following will work. The padding-top:100% keeps a 1:1 ratio for the circle-cropper div. Set an inline background image, center it, and use background-size:cover to hide any excess.

CSS

```
.circle-cropper {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="circle-cropper" role="img" style="background-image:url(myrectangle.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: I used an img tag with no src attribute as my HTML element of choice so I didn't have to worry about a div being a block-level element stupidness. Probably breaks some rules about accessibility...

Comment: Great for responsive layouts.

Comment: @BrianPeterson just for anyone who's reading this, I've recently found that to make this accessible add role="img" to the div. This will let screen readers know to treat it as an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it like that:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style>
        .round {
            display:block;
            width: 55px;
            height: 55px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding:5px 4px;
        }
        .round img {
            width: 45px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="round">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: pls put further explanation

Answer (score 2):

This one works well if you know height and width:

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: '50%';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

via https://medium.com/@chrisnager/center-and-crop-images-with-a-single-line-of-css-ad140d5b4a87

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me:

**CSS**

```
.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: no-repeat 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.round img {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="round">
   <img src="test.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this very same problem and couldn't find a decent solution other than having the div with the image as background and the img tag inside of it with visibility none or something like this.

One thing I might add is that you should add a `background-size: cover` to the div, so that your image fills the background by clipping it's excess.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .round_img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    var cw = $('.round_img').width();
    $('.round_img').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img class="round_img" src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suryakiran/1xqs4ztc/

Comment: Could you explain more in the body of your answer?

Comment: add this also in head part (<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>)