# clip-path not working on image in chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying to clip my images so that they are all circles; however, using css clip-path doesn't appear to be working? What am I doing wrong? I think I am using the spec correctly.

Here is my CSS:

```
img{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50%, 50%, 50%);
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle of this code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/vLer8/

What am I doing wrong? And how can I clip my images so that they are all circles?

Comment: Have you looked into something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577371/how-to-make-rectangular-image-appear-circular-with-css

Comment: @BuddhistBeast yes, that clips it, but leaves the margin still as a square.

Comment: Hmm, would this work? http://jsfiddle.net/vLer8/1/

Comment: It appears that the webkit-clip-path has an unknown compatibility with most browsers... In fact, it only works on Google Chrome.

Comment: Really, your best bet is border radius. It doesn't even look like webkit-clip-path: circle() is supported by any browsers. You can tell because the rect() and ellipsis() will work but not the circle.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Can you post that as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are going to want to go through a different approach as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vLer8/1/).
The reason being that most browsers are not compatible with the `-webkit-clip-path`, as far as research has shown and even less are compatible with the circular function of that.

With that being said ,your best bet will be using the border radius approach, which dictates that you probably want to have the height/width to be the exact same when in use. Here is the example HTML/CSS below from my JsFiddle:

```css
img {
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB1OV.jpg" 
     width="200px" height= "200px"/>
```

Which will still render your photo to be a circle, and it easily used. If you want to do anything that is not circular, then the webkit would be a good approach as seen in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLer8/2/)