# Image border-radius

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

Im creating android application with the help of **ionic famework**.
Im having this problem with the UI.
Im using [lists](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-thumbnails) in ionic to show the today's deals given by the shops.

Im making the thumbnails as round by the property `border-radius:100%` , but when a rectangle image is placed my thumbnail is messed up. Its good when i use sqare images. But im creating this application which have to support all shaped images. 
**Find the screenshot below** to know how rectangle image is responding with `border-radius:100%`

[image]

I want to get my thumbnails round in shape without being stretched. Image of expected list is given below
[image]

Is there any way to make the thumbnail in ionic framework as round ?

```
<div class="list">

    <!--.....................loop........................................................-->
            <a class="item item-icon-right item-thumbnail-left" href="#">

                <img style="border-radius: 100%;"  src="img/sample.jpg">
                <h2>HEADINGG</h2>
                <p>Details : Hey guys i saw that there was no thread for p300, so i decided to make one (this is the support and development thread) Do this at your own risk 1=Root your funbook It is rooted but sometimes it is not rooted so you must visit this page</p>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-right stable"></i>
            </a>            
    <!--.....................loop........................................................-->    
        </div>
```

I think i have to do something with the CSS . I dont know what to do.

Comment: did you try item-avatar

Comment: Please check this if it helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577371/how-to-make-rectangular-image-appear-circular-with-css

Comment: @sakir yes, i tried and the problem is the same. cant use rectangle images

Answer (score 0):

It's better to **crop** the *square* part of your images which you would like to display in your page in a circular-shape. That's because `border-radius:100%;` works like a charm for square-shaped images.

Here's a **[Live DEMO](http://jsbin.com/todinegemovu/1/edit)** !

Comment: i dont have an option to crop the image. Because this images are uploaded by the users. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577371/how-to-make-rectangular-image-appear-circular-with-css

This link helped me. Now im able to show circular image.

Answer (score 0):

try using only avatar

it seems avatar css something like this,

```
.avatar {
    border-radius: 95px;
}

<img class="avatar"  src="img/sample.jpg">
```

also I guess u need remove thumnail clases
u can edit here

Answer (score 0):

Fact:
Only square objects will be rendered as a circle with CSS border-radius: 100% or 50%.

So you have to give the image itself the same width and height.

...or I just didn't understand your problem^^

Comment: i know that. But i have to render rectangluar objects  also. I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577371/how-to-make-rectangular-image-appear-circular-with-css

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to set the border-radius with height and width.

```
<img src="" class="icon-round"></div>

    .icon-round {
       border-radius: 50%;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px; 
    }
```