# Making a whole image round in shape while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a whole image in a circle form(without cropping or hiding any part of it) while maintaining the aspect ratio.
I want to use only css.

I tried this:

```
#propic
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
background-size:cover;
display:block;
border-radius:100px;
-webkit-border-radius:100px;
-moz-border-radius:100px;
}
```

which does show my image in a circle form but doesnt maintain the aspect ratio.
Again I tried this:

```
#propic
{
width:150px;
height:auto;
background-size:cover;
display:block;
border-radius:100px;
-webkit-border-radius:100px;
-moz-border-radius:100px;
}
```

which does maintain the aspect ratio but the shape becomes oval.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `border-radius: 50%`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make rectangular image appear circular with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577371/how-to-make-rectangular-image-appear-circular-with-css)

Comment: Please show your HTML also.

Comment: @web-tiki i suppose i didnt ask about how to make a rectangular image circular(which i am able to do and i did even)

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcmg1v88/) if you are using `img`

Comment: @k-nut yes i did but didnt work.

Comment: @Vitorino Fernandes yes its partly what i want. Actually the fiddle hides the rest of the image, but what i actually require is to show the whole of image shrinked into a circle maintaining the aspect ratio.

Comment: the image will get stretched if you use it with aspect ratio

Comment: [**stretched image**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcmg1v88/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by 'maintain aspect ratio` since the div will be a circle. If you maintain the aspect ratio on a wide image there will be a blank area top and bottom to fit the width of the circle

```css
#propic {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/);
    background-position: center;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="propic"></div>
```

As an alternative you can crop the image left and right so that the image is still 100% tall with

```
background-size:auto 100%;
```

[**JSfiddle 2nd Option**](http://jsfiddle.net/b48ux6d0/1/)

Comment: Actually i wanted to do something like what google does but instead of cropping the image.

Comment: Perhaps you'd better show us what it is you are trying to do because it's not clear.

Comment: When we set our profile pic in gmail or g+ we 1st need to crop out the area we want to set as profile pic. But here what i want is to avoid all these cropping matter and just display the whole image as a circle and not to squeeze or stretch the image while displaying as a circle. Was i able to clear myself?

Comment: Not really...If the image isn't to stretch or be cropped it just can't be rectangular AND fit in a circle.

Comment: If it cant be rectangular can it be a square?

Comment: A square image is the ideal

Comment: `background-size: auto 100%;` was exactly what I was going for to get a centered round image of a wide image and not stretching it. I ended up with this:

```css
.my-avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('data:image/jpg;base64, mybase64urldatastream');
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```