# How to fit img into div circle ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm beginner in HTML/CSS.

I've created some div that looks like a circle.  I want to put facebook image into that circle,  but as a circle logo.

[image: Click to see IMAGE]

***HTML***

```
<div class="social" id="social1"> Facebook
  <a href="www.facebook.com">
    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" width="106" height="106"/> 
     </a>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
div {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 55px;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     border: 2px solid black;
     text-align:center;
   }

img {
     width: 100%;
     height : 100%;
     object-fit: contain;
    }
```

How to fit img into div circle ?

Comment: You could make the image a background-image of the div.

Comment: overflow : hidden; have you tried that ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577371/how-to-make-rectangular-image-appear-circular-with-css

Comment: [`object-fit` isn't supported in IE or Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```css
.social .facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="social" id="social1">
  <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically there are two ways to achieve this.

1. You could add `border-radius: 50%;` to the `img` element.
2. You could add `overflow: hidden;` to the `div` element.

Both will work. You should remove the "Facebook" string to get proper positioning of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. The text content "facebook" of the DIV is taking up room and needs to be removed. It can be replaced by alt text to display if the image is not available, with a title attribute that typically displays as a tooltip. Height and width are not needed for the IMG element since it is specified in CSS:

```
<div class="social" id="social1">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
     <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png"
      alt="facebood" title="facebook"> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Besides this you only need to add `overflow: hidden` as a property for the `div` CSS

---

Alternatively if you want to support IE and Edge which (from @Blazemonger 's comment) don't support `object-fit`, you could add the image as a background attachment of the DIV and make the DIV itself the link element's content (without an alt text option):

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
   <div class="social" id="social1" title="facebook">
   </div>
</a>
```

and include

```
background-image: url("https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png");
background-size: cover;
overflow:hidden;
```

in CSS for the div element.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow:hidden;` + `position:relative`/`absolute` to not mind the text aside image :

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 55px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="social" id="social1">Facebook
  <a href="www.facebook.com">
    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" width="106" height="106" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a border radius in CSS to round the image like so:

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height : 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
 border-radius: 999px;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/zBGYgx

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this :

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 55px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
  <div class="social" id="social1"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
border-radius: 100%;
object-fit:cover
}
```

This will position the image so that it appears centered and cropped and round its edges.

Comment: Hi, I don't think object-fit is supported in IE (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-radius:100%` to your img css code segment as well.

```
img {
     width: 100%;
     height : 100%;
     border-radius:100%;
}
```