# HTML/CSS multiple rounded images

Tags: html, css, image, sass

I'm trying to create a gallery of rounded photos (mostly landscape rectangular images). It works for the first image but I don't know how to apply it to all the images while maintaining the rounded format. Any help would be appreciated since I'm still new to this.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="photos">
<img src="url">
<img src="url">
etc.. more images
</div>
```

Then my CSS:

```
.photos {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 50%;
}

img {
width: auto;
height: 100%;
margin-left: -50px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make rectangular image appear circular with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577371/how-to-make-rectangular-image-appear-circular-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.photos` with one image inside it, like:

```css
.photos {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  <img src="http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/cardigan-welsh-corgi/chasing-8_680-453.jpg">
</div>
<div class="photos">
  <img src="http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/cardigan-welsh-corgi/chasing-8_680-453.jpg">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having a div for each?

Comment: @MayaCat You need to use a parent `<div>` if your images are not perfectly square & of the same size. Another thing you can do is wrap this `.photos` div into another parent div `.photos-holder` and then achieve your objective. Its just a suggestion else it all depends on what you really need to achieve as your end result.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css, it works for all img tag inside of Photos

```css
 .photos img{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your css with this:

```
.photos img {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    img {
      width: auto;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: -50px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply put each image in its own `<div>` with a class `round` for instance.

```css
    .round {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='round'>
        <img src='yourImage'>
    </div>
    <div class='round'>
        <img src='yourImage'>
    </div>
```